# How do I make the control flow from one test class to another test class in testNG?

Tags: java, testng

I have 4 test cases and I want the first test case to run from Demo1.java and then run the other 2 test cases from Demo2.java and then return back to Demo1.java to execute the final test case.

Is there any way I can achieve this?
Thanks for your help.

- I have tried `priority` parameter but I guess that just checks for the priorities in the same test class

Here is a sample code -

**Demo1.java**

```java
class Demo1{

  @Test
  public void testOne(){ //This case should be executed first
  }

  @Test
  public void testFour(){ //This case should be executed last
  }

}
```

**Demo2.java**

```java
class Demo2{

  @Test
  public void testTwo(){ // This case should be executed 2nd in the order
  }

  @Test
  public void testThree(){ // This case should be executed 3rd in the order
  }
}
```

Comment: @FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.JVM)
@TestMethodOrder(Alphanumeric.class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The combination of **@dependsOnGroups** and **@dependsOnMethods** annotations provides the most scalable way of test sequencing across classes and methods in TestNG.

- **@dependsOnGroups** will help implement sequencing across classes
- **@dependsOnMethods** will help implement sequencing within a class

**Here is the working example using @dependsOnGroups and @dependsOnMethods:**

**Scenario:**

- There are 2 test classes - ATest.java, BTest.java
- ATest has 2 test methods - A1, A2
- BTest has 2 test methods - B1, B2
- The sequence of execution must be: A1, B1, B2, A2

**ATest.java**

```
public class ATest.java {

    @Test(groups = "group-a1")

    public void A1() {
        System.out.println("Test A1: Runs before B1");
    }

    @Test(dependsOnGroups = "group-b2")
    public void A2() {
        System.out.println("Test A2: Runs after B2");
    }
}
```

**BTest.java**

```
public class BTest {

    @Test(dependsOnGroups = "group-a1")
    public void B1() {
        System.out.println("Test B1: Runs after A1");
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "B1", groups = "group-b2")
    public void B2() {
        System.out.println("Test B2: Runs after B1");
    }
}
```

**Note:**
The above sequencing can be implemented by using just the **@dependsOnMethods** annotation only.

However, it is not recommended to use **@dependsOnMethods** across classes, as it would make it mandatory to have unique name for each test case method in the entire suite.

The use of **@dependsOnGroups** will allow flexibility in test naming, and make it easy to implement sequencing across classes, without hassle.

---

**More information:**

https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can order Junit test Case by help of

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.JVM)
@TestMethodOrder(Alphanumeric.class)
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
@TestMethodOrder(TestCaseLengthOrder.class)
```

for details you can follow this link [click for more detail turtorial](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/juni-test-execution-order/#:%7E:text=We%20will%20learn%20how%20to%20order%20tests%20in%20JUnit%204,execution%20for%20the%20test%20cases.)

Comment: I am using TestNG here. Is there other annotation similar to this in TestNG?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by following below approach.

Class TEST1 extends Class TEST2 :

```
public class TEST1 extends TEST2{
@Test(priority = 1)
public void testOne() {
    System.out.println("Test method one");
}

@Test(priority = 4)
public void testTwo() {
    System.out.println("Test method two");
}
```

}

Class TEST2 :

```
@Test(priority = 2)
public void testThree() {
    System.out.println("Test three method in Inherited test");
}

@Test(priority = 3)
public void testFour() {
    System.out.println("Test four method in Inherited test");
}
```

Comment: Both of My Test1 & Test2 classes extend BaseTest class already. So usage of inheritance won't be solution for me.